# UITableviewCell height according to In side another UITableviewCell height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout

`{ 
MainTitle 1
    {
    Subtitle 1
      ( item 1
        item 2
        item 3 )
},
{
    MainTitle 2
    {
     Subtitle 2
        ( item 1
         item 2
         item 3)
    }
}`

There is JSON data format that I have to display in `UITableview`. The data is restaurant's menu. I create `Table 1` for `MainTitle` display and `Table 1` cell inside another  `UITableview Table 2` for `Subtitle and item` `Subtitle` set as header and `item` as row.

Tableview cell height is dynamic so I set it `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for both tableview. `Table 1` cell height is set according to inside it `Table 2` height. `Table 2` is not scrollable, it's height is according to content height.

So, I want to set `Table 1 cell` height after loading `Table 2` all data.

Comment: I think nested table view isn't a good idea. You should try to handle them with only 1 `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

You could use proper UITableView sections and rows. Add "MainTitle" as Table Section and MainTitle's "Items" as Section Rows.

Comment: what about  "Subtitle"

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using one single tableview as mentioned by @trungduc and @Raj D

You should be able to use a custom tableview cell to layout the items the way you want, and you can always use buttons for items that need to be clickable (i.e. if you need to click on the menu items and show another view controller).

Here's a basic mockup of what I mean[image]:

You'll want to use a stack view within the cell and then dynamically generate the menu items based off your backing data model (this should allow it to obtain the correct intrinsic content size for UITableViewAutomaticDimension to size the cells correctly).

[image]

Here's an example of what I mean by dynamically adding the menu items when setting the submenu item of the custom cell:

```
- (void)setupMenuItemsStack:(NSArray <RPMenuItem *> *)menuItems {
    for (UIView *subview in self.menuItemsStack.arrangedSubviews) {
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:subview.constraints];
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (RPMenuItem *menuItem in menuItems) {
        UIButton *menuItemButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        [menuItemButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [menuItemButton setTitle:menuItem.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.menuItemsStack addArrangedSubview:menuItemButton];
    }
}
```

Depending on how you're structuring your model, the tableview methods would look something along these lines:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.menuList.menus.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.menuList.menus objectAtIndex:section] subMenus].count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.menuList.menus objectAtIndex:section] title];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RPMenuTableViewCell *cell = (RPMenuTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RPMenuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    RPSubMenu *subMenu = [[[self.menuList.menus objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] subMenus] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setSubMenu:subMenu];
    return cell;
}
```

Where the menu list is a top level list of menus and it cascades down from there (i.e. menu list holds an array of menus, menus hold an array of submenus, submenus hold an array of menu items).

```
@property (strong, nullable) RPMenuList *menuList;
```

Adding the ability to expand and contract (accordion style) to show the menu items would probably be a nice touch as well:

[image]

Comment: if you created demo then can you please share it.